# What's a good alternative to uint8_t when it is not provided by the compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, types, cuda

I'm using nvcc to compile a CUDA kernel. Unfortunately, nvcc doesn't seem to support `uint8_t`, although it does support `int8_t` (!). I'd just as soon not use `unsigned char`, for portability, readability, and sanity reasons. Is there another good alternative?

---

Just to forestall any possible misunderstanding, here are some details.

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2010 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Jun__7_18:56:31_PDT_2010
Cuda compilation tools, release 3.1, V0.2.1221
```

Code containing

```
int8_t test = 0;
```

is fine, but code containing

```
uint8_t test = 0;
```

throws an error message like

```
test.cu(8): error: identifier "uint8_t" is undefined
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C99 integer types are not "defined by the compiler" - they are defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Try:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Comment: Thanks. The availability of `int8_t` threw me. :)

Comment: Thank you! Solved big issue for me

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is no different from what Mac OS X uses:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

What is your concern about the portability of `unsigned char`? If the concern is that a `char` might not represent 8 bits of storage, then you can include a static assertion along the lines of:

```
typedef int Assert8BitChar[(CHAR_BIT == 8)? 0 : -1];
```

This will cause compilation to error out when the assumption is violated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to compile just fine with `nvcc`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t x = 0;
    return (int) x;
}
```

Comment: Not on my machine it doesn't, or I wouldn't have asked. This is precisely why I put all the detail in the original question -- to make it clear that it doesn't work for me.